# How do I create a Doobie Meta instance for MySQL using Play JSON?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, doobie

How do I implement basic serialization/deserialization at the query level using [Doobie](https://tpolecat.github.io), MySQL, and Play JSON?

Answer (score 2):

After scouring the internet for an answer regarding JSON specific type support within MySQL and JDBC, it seems `String` is all we have available (please chime in and correct me if this is wrong). IMO, the Doobie doc doesn't make this answer obvious, since the example provided uses a more rigorous example via PostGRES. Unfortunately, MySQL is anything but rigorous, but that's for another conversation.

For now, here's a simple example of a solution, this also assumes Play JSON Readers/Writers are in scope:

```
import doobie.util.meta.Meta
import play.api.libs.json._

def playJsonMeta[A: Reads: Writes]: Meta[A] = Meta[String].xmap[A](
  Json.parse(_).as[A],
  s => Json.stringify(Json.toJson(s))
)

implicit val fooMeta: Meta[Foo] = playJsonMeta[Foo]
```

Do note, this will throw an exception if deserialization fails.